# WSO2 Self Registration Confirmation Email

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a client using the UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub to register new users. This works until I configure WSO2 IS to send a confirmation email.

in identity-mgt.properties I set:

```
Identity.Listener.Enable=true
Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=true
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=true
Notification.Expire.Time=7200
Notification.Sending.Enable=true 
Authentication.Policy.Enable=true
```

Now when the client call UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub.registerUser(), the user is added to the user store but no email is sent and the client receives the following exception:

```
SEVERE: null
org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub.UserInformationRecoveryServiceIdentityMgtServiceExceptionE(uxception: UserInformationRecoveryServiceIdentityMgtServiceExceptionException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub.UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub.registerUser(UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub.java:685)
at com.ijet.wso2is.client.UserInformationRecoveryServiceClient.registerBjnUser(UserInformationRecoveryServiceClient.java:191)
at com.ijet.wso2is.client.UserInformationRecoveryServiceClient.main(UserInformationRecoveryServiceClient.java:69)
```

The following is the client code of interest.

```
UserIdentityClaimDTO claim = new UserIdentityClaimDTO();
    claim.setClaimUri("http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress");
    claim.setClaimValue("testee@xyz.com");
    claimList.add(claim);

    claim = new UserIdentityClaimDTO();
    claim.setClaimUri("http://wso2.org/claims/givenname");
    claim.setClaimValue("Testee");
    claimList.add(claim);

    claim = new UserIdentityClaimDTO();
    claim.setClaimUri("http://wso2.org/claims/lastname");
    claim.setClaimValue("Tester");
    claimList.add(claim);

    serviceStub.registerUser(TEST_USERNAME, 
            "Password#1", 
            claimList.toArray(new UserIdentityClaimDTO[claimList.size()]), 
            null, 
            null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on IS 5.0.0?  I went through the code and it seems that the sending of emails is commented out. Simply commenting it in didn't work.
But it worked for me, if you register the user without specifying a password. In that use case the server runs through a different part of code which really sends out emails.